# How to logically combine two controllers in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I have module named `dashboard` and `PlanningController` inside. The controller has become too big and I want to split it into several separate controllers.

Now I have the following actions in `PlanningController`:

```
/dashboard/planning/purchase
/dashboard/planning/purchase-create
/dashboard/planning/purchase-update

/dashboard/planning/supplier
/dashboard/planning/supplier-create
/dashboard/planning/supplier-update
```

But I want to have 2 separate controllers `PurchaseController` and `SupplierController` which will be logically combined into a folder `planning`:

```
/dashboard/planning/purchase
/dashboard/planning/purchase/create
/dashboard/planning/purchase/update

/dashboard/planning/supplier
/dashboard/planning/supplier/create
/dashboard/planning/supplier/update
```

I read that Yii2 does not support subfolders in controllers. How do I merge two controllers into one folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you want to achieve there are multiple ways to handle this.

## Nested Modules

You can use [nested modules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-modules#nested-modules) to structure your code. Create a `planning` sub-module inside of `modules/dashboard/modules`. Then in the dashboard's `Module` class add the nested module for example like this:

```php
namespace app\modules\dashboard;

use app\modules\dashboard\modules\planning\Module as PlanningModule;
use yii\base\Module as BaseModule;

class Module extends BaseModule
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->modules = [
            'planning' => [
                'class' => PlanningModule::class,
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

That way you can separate all code related to your planning controllers into its own sub-module. Also, it will help you avoid any potential conflicts in routes.

## Controller Map

The property [`yii\base\Module::$controllerMap`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-map) allows you to use controllers that doesn't match the default yii's naming and folder structure conventions. With that you can place your `PurchaseController` and `SupplierController` into folder `modules/dashboard/controllers/planning` then set the map in your module class like this:

```php
namespace app\modules\dashboard;

use app\modules\dashboard\controllers\planning\PurchaseController;
use app\modules\dashboard\controllers\planning\SupplierController;
use yii\base\Module as BaseModule;

class Module extends BaseModule
{
    public $controllerMap = [
        'purchase' => PurchaseController::class,
        'supplier' => SupplierController::class,
    ];
}
```

If you use this approach and you want routes to contain the "/planning/" part you will have to set up specific url rules.

## Standalone Actions

If you only want to split the code of `PlanningController` because it is getting too big, but you are ok with keeping it as single controller. You can extract the action code into [standalone action classes](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#standalone-actions).
For example you can create `PurchaseCreateAction` class in `modules/dashboard/controllers/actions/planning` folder like this:

```php
namespace app\modules\dashboard\controllers\actions\planning;

use yii\base\Action;
use yii\web\Response;

class PurchaseCreateAction extends Action
{
    // string because we will return rendered form view and
    // Response because we will return redirect after successful create
    public function run(): string|Response
    {
         // ... action logic

         // to redirect
         return $this->controller->redirect(...);

         // to render view
         return $this->controller->render(...);
    }
}
```

You can include the standalone action in your planning controller like this:

```
namespace app\modules\dashboard\controllers;

use app\modules\dashboard\controllers\actions\planning\PurchaseCreateAction;
use yii\web\Controller;

class PlanningController extends Controller
{
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'purchase-create' => PurchaseCreateAction::class,
            // ... other actions
        ];
    }
}
```